# WebRequest removing Fragment from the Uri

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, uri, fragment-identifier

I want to open the following page:

> http://www.google.com/search?q=dvd+player&tbm=shop&hl=en&aq=f#q=car+speaker+&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vbtSTqTPDKXniAKy0-iDAw&ved=0CC0QpwUoAA&tbs=cat:895%2Cprice%3A1%2Cppr_min%3A50%2Cppr_max%3A99.99&tbm=shop&tbo=&fp=1&biw=851&bih=426&cad=b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.

but when I try to open it using `WebRequest` class, it removes the "Fragment" (which is not a Uri Fragment in this case) from the url, and tries to open the following url instead:

> http://www.google.com/search?q=dvd+player&tbm=shop&hl=en&aq=f

How can I do to open exactly that url?

I tried encoding the `#` character, but that does not seem to be working.

**Edit:**
I know what the URL is, what the fragment is, and all of it. What I'm asking is if there is a way to override what the `Uri` class does. (To take the Uri, and remove what is after `#` and place it in the `Fragment` property, etc), so I can query that url, instead of the modified url.

Comment: Disable JavaScript once and you'll see that it is a fragment that is being processed client-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the fragment in your example doesn't do exactly what a fragment was designed to do, it's still providing **client-side** data to the browser to take action after the page has been initially loaded. If you watch carefully when clicking on the link, you'll see the title of the page starts out as "dvd player" (from the original query string) but then changes to "car speaker" after the page has loaded from the server and the client-side script executes.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the # represents a fragment (usually an anchor in web pages) and isn't really part of the URL, it just takes the browser to a specific part of the page, and is process on the client-side only.

In other words, it's not part of the URI request.

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the
> URI: namely, its processing is **exclusively client-side with no
> participation from the server** — of course the server typically helps
> to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the
> processing of fragments.
>
> When an agent (such as a Web browser)
> requests a resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the
> server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for
> the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the
> resource according to the document type and fragment value.

http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#media-type-fragid

Comment: That makes sense, but did you take a look at the URL I posted? Did you see what is after the `#`? It does not seem to be an identifier of a section of the page...

Comment: While the fragment in your example doesn't do exactly what a fragment was designed to do, it's still providing **client-side** data to the browser to take action after the page has been initially loaded. If you watch carefully when clicking on the link, you'll see the title of the page starts out as "dvd player" (from the original query string) but then changes to "car stereo" after the page has loaded from the server and the client-side script executes.

Comment: @AdamMaras Could you post this comment as an answer so I can accept it? You're totally right about it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange one in that the `fragment` really shouldn't be parsed by the server. But, in your example url, the fragment most definitely is being used (maybe in the google JS, client side?)

Here's a quick hack that seems to do what you need by encoding the entire query:

```
string str =
"http://www.google.com/search?q=dvd+player&tbm=shop&hl=en&aq=f#q=car+speaker+&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vbtSTqTPDKXniAKy0-iDAw&ved=0CC0QpwUoAA&tbs=cat:895%2Cprice%3A1%2Cppr_min%3A50%2Cppr_max%3A99.99&tbm=shop&tbo=&fp=1&biw=851&bih=426&cad=b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.";

string[] arr = str.Split( '?' );
string uriString = arr[0] + "?" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode( arr[1] );
var uri = new Uri( uriString );
var request = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( uri );
```

**Edit**
In retrospect, the `fragment` is being used on the client side JS, not server side.

A better idea may be to understand google's Url's, i.e., your Uri should be:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=car+speaker&hl=en&tbs=cat:895,price:1,ppr_min:50&tbm=shop
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment is a client-side mechanism, and thus has no use on the server. Any data you pass back to the server would be in the querystring, so what benefit do you see of attempting to pass a fragment back?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this variable on client side then you can use this javascript code

```
 <script>
 if(window.location.hash) {
    console.log(window.location.hash); 
    window.location.hash = window.location.hash;
 } 
</script>
```